# Equality p-Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplacian

Prove that $$\Delta_p u= \text{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)=|\nabla u|^{p-2} ({(p-2)\Delta_{\infty}} u+\Delta u)$$

I tried do this from the definitions but it didn't lead me to the any good conclusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\Delta_\infty u$?  For that matter, what is $\Delta u$?

Comment: First, this is a straight forward application of the div operation. For a scalar $f$ and a vector $G$ $$\text{div} (f G) = f \nabla \cdot G + G \cdot \nabla f$$ which can be seen as a product rule in higher dimensions. In your case, you have $f = \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{p-2}, G = \nabla u$. Second, as stated in the other comment, it would help if you explained what $\Delta_{\infty}$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: Thanks, $\triangle_\infty u=(D^{2} u \nabla u) \cdot \nabla u$

Comment: You've now neglected to explain what $D^{2}$ is. I'm guessing it is some sort of differentiation operator, but which one? And is it only applied to $u$ or to $u \nabla u$?